windows control GNOME
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME Desktop Environment.
Also, I can choose at login other combination of Desktop Environment/Windows Manager:

GNOME classic
GNOME on X11
Ubuntu
Ubuntu on X11

I like GNOME also beside installed GNOME Extensions, but I notice with this Desktop Environment I can't see the icon at upper/right to minimize and maximize windows.
If I choose option 3 or 4, I am able to see icons, but GNOME doesn't have the min/max functionality. How do I fix this?

Install GNOME Tweaks
If not already installed you can follow this guide
Then select Window Titlebars and select on Maximise and Minimise options.


ok , thanks , but why GNOME consider these function as optinal ? they should be activated by default !
